# Is it possible to block access to a DB based on IP?

Tags: security, ip-address, database, data

We're looking to beef up the security on a site, among other things we thought of trying to block access to the DB based on IP (in a similar way you can do a FTP lock dependent on IP), so that only the static IP of our VPS can access it as well as our local office IP (also static).

Is this a standard approach, I tried searching for it to see any notes on implementation / best practices, but I could see anything written about it?

Comment: Check [this][1], our neighborhoods from SO.
Might could help you
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127602/restrict-sql-server-connection-to-specific-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to increase security for connections to remote server applications, you might look into setting up a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

If your VPS is using the Plesk control panel (as in your previous questions), you can use their [VPN Module](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.0.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-unix-vpn-module-guide/index.htm?fileName=5578.htm). As stated there:

> Virtual Private Networking technologies allow communications between
>   geographically distributed LAN segments over public networks. VPN
>   message traffic passes through public networking infrastructures, such
>   as the Internet, via secure tunnel protocols.
>
> One of the most useful implementations of VPN is allowing access to a
>   local network for a single remote host. For example, if a user needs
>   to get access to a remote network from his home computer, they must
>   establish a VPN connection.

You can then specify the remote IP address (or host name) of your local office to restrict access to just that, as covered under [VPN Preferences](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.0.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-unix-vpn-module-guide/index.htm?fileName=5578.htm). A VPN can also be added to a server without a control panel, and setup depends on your environment.

Another option is to create a firewall rule to only allow your local office's IP address to connect to the IP or port number that your database is accessible on. For example, MySQL uses the [default port](http://kb.parallels.com/en/391) of 3306. See [this](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.0.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-unix-firewall-module-guide/index.htm?fileName=51137.htm) for configuring the firewall in Plesk, or [this](http://www.creativeintensity.com/index.php/allowing-mysql-access-from-specific-ip-addresses-only-in-linux/) for a server without a control panel.

Last but not least, you could configure the database to be accessible only on a subdomain or another domain, and then restrict access to this to just the IP address of your local office.

Comment: +2 for background research / memory "If your VPS is using the Plesk control panel (as in your previous questions)"